# VBA: XML parsing text with single tag <br/> into two separate strings (MSXML2)

Tags: excel, xml-parsing, msxml, vba

I’ve a XML file looking like this:

```
<xml> 
    <title>This is the title</title> 
    <text>This is the first line<br/>This is the second line.</text> 
    <title>This is another title</title> 
    <text>This is another first line<br/>This is another second line.</text>
</xml>​
```

I want now phase this XML file with a VBA script and MSXML2.

I’m able to get the full text tag (both lines) with `selectNodes` or `selectSingleNode` method.

But how I can get first line and second line of my `<text>` tag into two different strings?